# Let $A$, $B$ be two $3\times3$ commuting matrices, where $A$ is nilpotent and $\operatorname{tr}B = 0$. Prove that $ABA = O$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $3\times3$ commuting matrices, where $A$ is nilpotent and $\operatorname{tr}B = 0$.
Prove that $ABA = 0$.

#### Progress

I know that $ABA=0 \implies A^2B=0$. Here
$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& a_{12}a_{23} \\ 0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
or
$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0& 0 \\ 0&0&0\\a_{21}a_{32}&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
$b_{11}+b_{22}+b_{33}=0$. So I have to prove that $b_{11}a_{12}a_{23}=0$ or $b_{33}a_{21}a_{32}=0$.

Comment: It might help if you tell us what have you done so far?

Comment: I know that ABA=0 => A^2B=0.
A^2=[0,0,a12*a23;0,0,0;0,0,0] or A^2=[0,0,0;0,0,0;0,0,a21*a32]

b11+b22+b33=0 so I Have to prove that b11*a12*a23=0 or b33*a21*a32=0

Comment: Edit, posted an error!
A^2=[0,0,0;0,0,0;a21*a32,0,0]

Answer (score 5):

The progress from the OP is incorrect.  There is no reason to believe that $A$ has zeroes in certain places.  For example, take $$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}10&3&7\\-4&-1&-3\\-13&-4&-9\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$

We have $A^3=0$ and $$A^2=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}-3&-1&-2\\3&1&2\\3&1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$
which has no zero entries at all.

We know that all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are zero, since $A$ is nilpotent.  We also know that the eigenvalues of $B$ sum to zero, since that is the trace of $B$, although this information is not needed.

Now, consider the minimal polynomial of $A$.  It is either $x, x^2$, or $x^3$.  If it is either $x$ or $x^2$, then $A^2=0$ and hence $A^2B=0$.  If instead it is $x^3$ then its minimal polynomial coincides with its characteristic polynomial.  Hence, since $A,B$ commute, we [may conclude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices) that $B$ is a polynomial of $A$, i.e. there is some polynomial $p(x)$ such that $B=p(A)$.

Now, because $A,B$ commute they can be [simultaneously triangulated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices), assuming that your ground field is algebraically closed (such as $\mathbb{C}$).  Choose $S$ so that $SAS^{-1}$ and $SBS^{-1}$ are each upper triangular.  They have their eigenvalues on the diagonals, so in particular $SAS^{-1}$ has zeroes on the diagonal.  Since $B=p(A)$, $SBS^{-1}=p(SAS^{-1})$ and in particular $SBS^{-1}$ also has zeroes along the diagonal.

Hence each of $SAS^{-1}$ and $SBS^{-1}$ is of the form $$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&\star &\star\\0&0&\star\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$
and the product of any three such matrices is $0$; in particular $A^2B=0$.

Comment: Nice solution. +1.

Comment: I dont get this, will not ab3 and ab1 all be in northeast corner:

[0,0,a;0,0,0;0,0,0]*[b1,x,x;0,b2,x;0,0,b3]=[0,0,ab3;0,0,0;0,0,0]?
and [b1,x,x;0,b2,x;0,0,b3]*[0,0,a;0,0,0;0,0,0]=[0,0,ab1;0,0,0;0,0,0]?

Comment: @Matrix, you are quite right, I fixed it.

Comment: If you change basis, then yes, you can assume that $A^2$ has zeros everywhere apart from the $(1,3)$ entry. For instance, take a Jordan basis. So it is possible that OP is not incorrect; maybe they are just skipping a step that they find easy.

Comment: You are being serious about the ground field not having been specified "assuming that your ground field is algebraically closed". Very good (although that particular hypothesis is not actually needed). However, then you should have stumbled upon the additional requirement that the characteristic not be$~3$ (see my answer). How did this escape you? Well you forgot that polynomials can have constant terms. This is also where the hypothesis $\operatorname{tr}B=0$ must really be used, contrary to what you say.

Answer (score 1):

If $A^2=0$ then $ABA=BA^2=0$ and we are done, so assume $A^2\neq0$. Since the degree of the minimal polynomial of cannot exceed the size of the matrix (by Cayley-Hamilton if you like), one has $A^3=0$.

Chose a vector $v$ with $A^2\cdot v\neq 0$, then $[A^2\cdot v, A\cdot v,v]$ is a linearly independent family, hence a basis. Call the basis $\def\B{\mathcal B}\B$, then after base change to this basis we get
$$
  A'=\operatorname{Mat}_\B(A)=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}.
$$
Similarly base-change $B$ to $B'=\operatorname{Mat}_\B(A)$, then $A',B'$ satisfy the same hypotheses as given for $A,B$. From commutation of $B'$ with $A'$ one easily sees that the three diagonal entries of $B'$ are equal, say to$~b$. We then have $\operatorname{tr} B=3b=0$. Then *provided the field$~K$ this is over does not have characteristic$~3$*, we conclude $b=0$ in particular the top left entry of$~B'$ is$~0$, and this implies $B'(A')^2=0$, and $ABA=0$.

---

In characteristic$~3$ the result is false, as $B'=A'+I$ shows.

---

A less coordinate-oriented approach would be to set $V=\ker(A)$ and $W=\ker(A^2)$, then by commutation of $A,B$ these subspaces are $B$-stable. Hence $B$ acts on the quotient spaces $V/\{0\}\simeq V$, $W/V$ and $K^3/W$, all of dimension$~1$, so the action of $B$ is by scalars. The action of$~A$ induces isomorphisms between these quotients (from $K^3/W$ to $W/V$ to $V/\{0\}$), which intertwine (commute with) the action of $B$, showing that $B$ acts by *the same* scalar$~b$ on all three spaces. The trace of $B$ then equals $3b=0$, and the rest proceeds as above.